# TCP/IP error while trying to load data to Elasticsearch from SQL Server using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am new to Logstash.I am trying to load data from Sql server to Elasticsearch using Logstash,while doing so I get the below error:

```
C:\logstash-5.0.2>bin\logstash -f C:\logstash-5.0.2\bin\Crash_Data.conf
Using JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8 retrieved from C:\ProgramData\Oracle\
java\javapath\java.exe
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Could not find log4j2 configuration at path /logstash-5.0.2/config/log4j2.proper
ties. Using default config which logs to console
15:33:47.206 [[main]-pipeline-manager] ERROR logstash.agent - Pipeline aborted d
ue to error {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: Java::ComMicrosoftSq
lserverJdbc::SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host Device_Crash_Reporting, port 1433 has failed. . Verify the connection properties. Make sure
 that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP conn
ections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked
by a firewall.".>, :backtrace=>["com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
.makeFromDriverError(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException.java:191)",
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLSe
rverException(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerException.java:242)", "com.m
icrosoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/IOB
uffer.java:2369)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(com/microsoft/s
qlserver/jdbc/IOBuffer.java:551)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnec
tion.connectHelper(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1962)",
 "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(com/microsoft/sqlserver
/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1627)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCo
nnection.connectInternal(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:1
458)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(com/microsoft/s
qlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java:772)", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLS
erverDriver.connect(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.java:1168)", "R
UBY.connect(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/seq
uel/adapters/jdbc.rb:222)", "RUBY.make_new(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby
/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:116)", "RUBY.make_new(C:/l
ogstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_p
ool/threaded.rb:228)", "RUBY.available(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9
/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:201)", "RUBY._acquire
(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connect
ion_pool/threaded.rb:137)", "RUBY.acquire(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/
1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:151)", "RUBY.sync(
C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connecti
on_pool/threaded.rb:282)", "org.jruby.ext.thread.Mutex.synchronize(org/jruby/ext
/thread/Mutex.java:149)", "RUBY.sync(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/g
ems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:282)", "RUBY.acquire(C:
/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection
_pool/threaded.rb:150)", "RUBY.hold(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/ge
ms/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool/threaded.rb:106)", "RUBY.synchronize
(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/databas
e/connecting.rb:285)", "RUBY.test_connection(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jru
by/1.9/gems/sequel-4.40.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:295)", "RUBY.prepare
_jdbc_connection(C:/logstash-5.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-j
dbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:171)", "RUBY.register(C:/logstash-5
.0.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.1.3/lib/logstash/inputs/
jdbc.rb:191)", "RUBY.start_inputs(C:/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/p
ipeline.rb:319)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)", "RU
BY.start_inputs(C:/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:318)",
"RUBY.start_workers(C:/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:195
)", "RUBY.run(C:/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:153)", "R
UBY.start_pipeline(C:/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:250)"]}

15:33:47.721 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstas
h API endpoint {:port=>9600}
15:33:50.261 [LogStash::Runner] WARN  logstash.agent - stopping pipeline {:id=>"
main"}

C:\logstash-5.0.2>
```

I have checked the port to sql server and everything but still no luck.Can someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: Do you have a firewall preventing the connection maybe?

Comment: Is there a way to check whether any firewall is blocking  the connection?